# My loop cuts are not going around my whole model

Tags: mesh, objects, workflow, vertices, topology

The loop cuts aren't going around the model as you can see they stop once it gets to the floor I checked for NGONs by selecting by trait and none where found I'm stumped.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There may be split edges, so that the floor and the arch aren't actually connected. Also, through the holes it looks like the selection goes on to something underneath the floor. What does it look from in bottom view?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the face that I've selected in the image below (I'm usin a non-default colour theme, so my selections are blue, not orange).

[image]

If that ledge really needs to be there, you should give it some volume, but if you're not going to render any views where it's visible, you may just as well delete it, and the loop cut will work.

As it is now, Blender can't tell which direction the cut should go, so it stops before actually reaching that edge.

To delete the face, select it and press <kbd>X</kbd> followed by <kbd>F</kbd>. Then the loop cut will work as you expect.
If you really need that ledge, select the face and press <kbd>Y</kbd> or click *Mesh -> Vertices -> Split* to separate it from the rest of the mesh. If so, you should also consider solidifying it, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> followed by <kbd>S</kbd> or *Mesh -> Faces -> Solidify*. To set the thickness, enter it in the tool options at the bottom of the tool shelf on the left side. To show the tool shelf if it's not visible, press <kbd>T</kbd> or click *View -> Tool Shelf*.

[image]

Now the loop cut will work. However, the ledge will not be cut, since it's no longer connected to the rest of the mesh. You will need to cut it as well, if you need it to be cut at the same places as the archway.

[image]